# What would browsers need to support the HTML5 document outline?

Tags: html, browser, accessibility, semantic-markup

In short, the HTML5 specification allows us to use multiple `h1` elements. However, there is a fair amount of controversy over this feature, with 2 major claims as to why not to use it.

**1. SEO:** Mainly dubious claims that search bots do not support it, and unsubstantiated claims it will "confuse" them. However, let us defer such speculation to other postings.

**2. User agents do not support it:** Unfortunately, the reasoning behind this seems less clear than the SEO claims.

The MDN article for [Sections and Outlines of an HTML5 Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) features the following warning:

> Important: There are currently no known implementations of the outline algorithm in graphical browsers or assistive technology user agents, although the algorithm is implemented in other software such as conformance checkers. Therefore the outline algorithm cannot be relied upon to convey document structure to users. Authors are advised to use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.

But it's not like a document which uses the new document outline structure doesn't work. To see for myself how browser react, I created some samples that make use of having multiple stand-alone articles on the same page.

**HTML4:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Outline HTML4</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Section List</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>Alpha</h2>
                <p>Alpha is the first letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h3>Subheading</h3>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Beta</h2>
                <p>Beta is the second letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h3>Subheading</h3>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HTML5:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Outline HTML5</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Section List</h1>
            <section>
                <h1>Alpha</h1>
                <p>Alpha is the first letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h2>Subheading</h2>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h1>Beta</h1>
                <p>Beta is the second letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h2>Subheading</h2>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only potential visual issue I see would be that the browser might render all the `h1` tags the same size, however the default user-agent styles of both Firefox and Chrome currently reduce the size of an `h1` tag inside `article`, `aside`, `nav`, and `section` tags (seeming to indicate browsers *do* recognize this feature). Additionally, we don't have any problems recognizing a second `h2` header means the end of the last `h2` section, so I don't see any reason we would have a visual problem with multiple `h1` tags.

While I can't speak for how those who depend on screen readers prefer to browse the web, Apple's VoiceOver does correctly identify each header level.

My question is, what *exactly* would a graphical browser or assistive technology have to do to "support" the outline that they don't do already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it's not like a document which uses the new document outline structure doesn't work.

Why wouldn't it work? They're just HTML elements, and the inclusion of multiple `h1` tags is well within a browsers rendering capacity.

Like you mentioned, an issue to consider is the styling. Unless you adjust the styles for different `h1`s, they may all share the same visual features, such as size.

> My question is, what *exactly* would a graphical browser or assistive technology have to do to "support" the outline that they don't do already?

The user agents render the HTML code. As mentioned before, the browsers can easily render multiple `h1`s and, [depending on implementation](http://caniuse.com/), HTML5 elements.

The [outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines), however, is something else. The outline is essentially a list of sections in the DOM. Normally, this outline can be presented to users in a useful and instructive way.

Using this [**HTML outlining tool**](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/), I punched in *http://www.dell.com*, and it generated a clean, organized outline of the site.

What the warning you highlighted is saying is that the HTML5 *outline algorithm* is not broadly supported and cannot convey similar useful results.

> [**4.3.10.1 Creating an outline**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines)
>
> There are currently no known implementations of the outline algorithm in graphical browsers or assistive technology user agents, although the algorithm is implemented in other software such as conformance checkers. ***Therefore the outline algorithm cannot be relied upon to convey document structure to users.*** Authors are advised to use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure. *(emphasis mine)*

This does not mean the code doesn't work, just that semantically it may be weak and/or useless.

More info:

- [The HTML5 Document Outline](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/)
- [4.3.10.1 Creating an outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines)

Comment: I certainly didn't think it wouldn't work, browser can make some truely horrifying code work :). But you raise a good point that outline generators might take issue with this. However I'm not aware of any such outline feature in any browser, be it supporting HTML4 or HTML5. So is it unfair, and perhaps invalid, to criticize browser for not implementing support, as this warning seems to be doing?

Comment: I didn't intend to be critical of the browsers for their lack of implementation.  I wanted to draw a distinction being rendering code and generating an outline. I've used both algorithms extensively. Haven't had any significant problems with either. But I believe all the hullabaloo over the HTML5 outline algorithm involves just that: *the outline*.

Comment: The spec writers take this seriously because it conveys the structure of the page. Web developers may not care as much because the page renders just fine.

Comment: Ok, and I didn't mean you were critical of browsers, but that the warning in the spec seemed to be. I can certainly see the advantages to being able to parse a document in a semantic way. I guess I'm just not sure in what way it was expected a browser would.

Comment: Honestly, the possible document outline parsing issue seems like a more-plausible source of concern for any possible SEO troubles. However, I'm personally going to throw that in the fear-of-new-technology bin unless someone can factually convince me otherwise.

Comment: I think an important question is: *When will the HTML5 Outline Algorithm be implemented, or at least start gaining some momentum?* I'm not sure it will even happen, which is why last year I reverted back to the standard HTML4 outline (h1-h6), except with HTML5 elements like `<section>` and `<article>` in the mix :-)

Comment: I guess the answer to that is, "Implemented in what?" Maybe Googlebot does, maybe it doesn't. If everything you need to interface with implements it or functions the same either way, I'm not sure it makes much difference.

Answer (score 4):

Take as an example Jaws screenreader:
http://webaim.org/resources/shortcuts/jaws#headings

It provides shortcut to go to the next heading of the same level. But with the addition of HTML5 `section` and `article` tags. It is subject to some precautions.

When you have such code:

```
<h1>Main title</h1>
<h2>sub part 1</h2>
<section>
   <h1>first section inside sub part 1</h1>
   <h2>subpart inside first section of sub part 1</h2>

</section>
<h2>sub part 2</h2>
```

If you are currently focusing `h2` *"sub part 1"* and you press on the key `2` you would expect to go to *"sub part 2"* (ie. the next heading of the same level) but the Assistive Technology will lead you to the next h2 in the DOM reading order.

For that exact reason, **you should respect the hierarchy of heading in the full document as though there were no section** (even if it respects HTML5).

Now, you can perfectly imagine to have two `h1` in the `body` but you expect to have some way to read the title of the current page without relying on the `title` tag which can contain some other elements like the web site name, the category/hierarchy in the web site. So you should use only one `h1` element in the `body` element for the title of the current page.

Comment: You make a fair point with screen-reader shortcuts. However it seems with at least some screen readers can handle HTML5 outline structure in an effective way. I decided to give the latest JAWS screen-reader demo a try (version 17), and pushing the `2` hotkey did not seem to jump through different sections. For example, after using `1` to jump into the first section, I was able to push `2` and jump to the sub-heading for that section, however after a subsequent press of the `2` key, Jaws stated "No more headings at level 2 in this section." Unless I'm mistaken, this means JAWS is outline aware.

Comment: We can't presume about the current or future screenreader implementation. I took Jaws shortcut list as an example; but not everyone uses a Jaws ot its version 17 (upgrade are expensive). There are a lot of existing, in development or to-be-announced accessibility software (screenreaders, voice activated, eye-tracking, ...), not all of them are relying on css (like fixed-width and size font screen display), and they do not use the same shortcut list. If we can give a way to go to the h2 in the section directly with one shortcut, let's do it.

Comment: This issue is definitely a tough one. On one hand, outline aware readers can be made more-accessible by using the HTML5 outline. On the other hand, assuming what this is true for some other screen readers (and I don't know for certain if it is or not), making documents for those unaware screen readers penalizes those using HTML5 outline aware ones. Worse still, there's no way to feature detect.

Comment: Also, it's the major problem of the "universal design" : people aren't the same. Some use spatial memory, others need cartography. And there is no way to detect it. A blind geek with a screenreader will have better user experience than an old man, unfamiliar with new technologies, with a perfect view. And they both might use the outline to navigate through the page.

Answer (score 3):

The styling modification is very superficial. You can see that in the example below, the h2 subheading to the h1 "gamma" heading is rendered in a larger font than the "h1" gamma heading itself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Outline HTML5</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Section List</h1>
            <section>
                <h1>Alpha</h1>
                <p>Alpha is the first letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h2>Subheading</h2>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
                <section>
                  <h1>Gamma</h1>
                  <p>Gamma is the third letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                  <h2>Subheading</h2>
                  <p>This is just filler.</p>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h1>Beta</h1>
                <p>Beta is the second letter of the greek alphabet.</p>
                <h2>Subheading</h2>
                <p>This is just filler.</p>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my opinion, browsers need to calculate the sectioning level of *every element* from the outline algorithm, and then expose it through a CSS pseudo-class - e.g. `div:level(3)` or `:matches(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):level(4)` or just `:level(2)` and also expose it as an element state through JavaScript e.g. `if (document.getElementById("myElement").level == 4) { ... }`

Comment: "the h2 subheading to the h1 'gamma' heading is rendered in a larger font than the 'h1' gamma heading itself" This is actually pretty funny to look at. Not the fact that browsers don't style h2 elements based on sectioning level the same way they do h1 elements, but seeing a level 3 h2 in a larger font than a level 3 h1 as a result of this limitation.

Comment: An interesting idea, if perhaps a little advanced compared to existing CSS. Has the W3C ever made a similar statement?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But in its present form, the outline algorithm is little more than a piece of wishful thinking. And until and unless browsers do something like this, and makes it genuinely useful to web authors and therefore to users, it's difficult to see why that should change.

Answer (score 0):

> What would browsers need to support the HTML5 document outline?

According to [*Outlines* in *HTML5 - A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines) browsers would need to support **sectioning content** and **sectioning root** elements.

The warning only says that so far (at the date of publishing) no implementations were known to the documents editor.

Comment: True, but can you clarify what exactly this means for a browser? Browsers have not traditionally generated outlines AFAIK, so what exactly should a browser do with such an outline?

Comment: As no such implementation exists, it would be speculative to say what exactly would mean that for a browser. Some answers to your question have concentrated on the visual representation of an outline. As the outline sounds like semantics to me, I'd say a browser could use it to understand document structure. E.g. one use could be to offer navigation between sections.